# Splitting a large Pandas Dataframe with minimal memory footprint

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame, which I would like to split into a test set and a train set for model building. However, I do not want to duplicate the DataFrame because I am reaching a memory limit.

Is there an operation, similar to pop but for a large segment, that will simultaneously remove a portion of the DataFrame and allow me to assign it to a new DataFrame? Something like this:

```
# Assume I have initialized a DataFrame (called "all") which contains my large dataset, 
# with a boolean column called "test" which indicates whether a record should be used for
# testing.
print len(all)
# 10000000 
test = all.pop_large_segment(all[test]) # not a real command, just a place holder
print len(all)
# 8000000
print len(test)     
# 2000000
```

Comment: As far as I know, the moment you do the assignment, pandas creates a copy. Would it work if you just store the indices of train and test?

Comment: Not answering the question, but perhaps other relevant ideas:
- Can't you split the dataset already when loading?
- Or use something like `dask` ( http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/  )?

Comment: The only why I know is to load them from an HDF5 table separately and do the split at load time, i.e. load some rows first as training and then the rest as split- can provide a proper answer is this sounds plausible...

Comment: Splitting the dataset on loading is what I suggested in my answer.  The only hitch is that you have to keep track of exactly which rows were loaded in the training set, then load the remainder, which with a ton of rows gets clunky.  You also have to make sure that you're really getting an unbiased sample, or your training will be off.  This does seem like something that would be a nice addition under the hood to Pandas machine learning abilities.

Comment: There's no way to have "something like pop" for DataFrames.  A DataFrame's size is an inherent part of its identity; there is no way to make it smaller or bigger.  You can only create a new DataFrame of a different size.  (Operations that appear to change the size of a DataFrame, like `drop`, actually just create a new DataFrame.)

Comment: What are the dtypes of your data frame? 1. If you don't need high precision then you may consider using float32 or even float16 instead of default float64. 2. If you had `df` already sorted by `'test'`, then you could use slicing: `df_train=df[:N]`, but sorting in place (without extra memory) is tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the space to add one more column, you could add one with a random value that you could then filter on for your testing.  Here I used uniform between 0 and 1, but you could use anything if you wanted a different proportion.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1], 'two':[6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6], 'three':[11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11]})
df['split'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=len(df))
```

Of course that requires you have space to add an entirely new column - especially if your data is very long, maybe you don't.

Another option would work, for example, if your data was in csv format and you knew the number of rows.  Do similar to the above with the `randomint`, but pass that list into the `skiprows` argument of Pandas `read_csv()`:

```
num_rows = 100000
all = range(num_rows)

some = np.random.choice(all, replace=False, size=num_rows/2)
some.sort()
trainer_df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=some)

rest = [i for i in all if i not in some]
rest.sort()
df = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=rest)
```

It's a little clunky up front, especially with the loop in the list comprehension, and creating those lists in memory is unfortunate, but it should still be better memory-wide than just creating an entire copy of half the data.

To make it even more memory friendly you could load the trainer subset, train the model, then overwrite the training dataframe with the rest of the data, then apply the model.  You'll be stuck carrying `some` and `rest` around, but you'll never have to load both halves of the data at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something similar as @jeff-l, i.e. keep your data frame on file. When you read it in as a csv, use the `chunksize` keyword. The following script illustrates this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

test = 5
m, n = 2*test, 3

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=numpy.random.random((m, n))
)

df['test'] = [0] * test + [1] * test 

df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)

for chunk in pandas.read_csv('tmp.csv', chunksize=test):
    print chunk
    del chunk
```

Comment: This pulls the data off disk in order though, and a training dataset should be an unbiased sample.  Although this would work if you knew the data was already randomly shuffled on disk..

Answer (score 1):

As other answers are more focused on the file reading, I guess you also can do something, if for any reason your DataFrame isn't read from a file.

Maybe you can take a look at the code of the [`DataFrame.drop` method](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/6d8c04ce64d975c2fd8c902c0e5df343805bd112/pandas/core/generic.py#L1847) and modify it in order to modify your DataFrame inplace (which the `drop` method already do) *and* get the other raws returned :

```
class DF(pd.DataFrame):
    def drop(self, labels, axis=0, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise'):
        axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
        axis_name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
        axis, axis_ = self._get_axis(axis), axis

        if axis.is_unique:
            if level is not None:
                if not isinstance(axis, pd.MultiIndex):
                    raise AssertionError('axis must be a MultiIndex')
                new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
            else:
                new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
            dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
            try:
                dropped.axes[axis_].set_names(axis.names, inplace=True)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            result = dropped

        else:
            labels = com._index_labels_to_array(labels)
            if level is not None:
                if not isinstance(axis, MultiIndex):
                    raise AssertionError('axis must be a MultiIndex')
                indexer = ~axis.get_level_values(level).isin(labels)
            else:
                indexer = ~axis.isin(labels)

            slicer = [slice(None)] * self.ndim
            slicer[self._get_axis_number(axis_name)] = indexer

            result = self.ix[tuple(slicer)]

        if inplace:
            dropped = self.ix[labels]
            self._update_inplace(result)
            return dropped
        else:
            return result, self.ix[labels]
```

Which will work like this:

```
df = DF({'one':[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1], 'two':[6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6], 'three':[11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11]})

dropped = df.drop(range(5), inplace=True)
# or :
# partA, partB = df.drop(range(5))
```

This example isn't probably really memory efficient but maybe you can figure out something better by using some kind of object oriented solution like this.

Comment: I guess this will still require extra space while doing that operation but maybe it can be used iteratively with small chunks. It might be faster than reading from a file.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Although again, it's splitting the data in order.  In the `partA` and `partB` results, you end up with the top half of the data in one and the bottom half of the data in the other. Biased samples unless your data is randomly shuffled on disk.

Comment: @JeffL. I guess it wont really be difficult to pick-up random values by using a list of random and unique integers smaller than the number of features as an argument for the drop function (like `random.sample(range(len(df)), n_wanted_values)` instead of a continuous range of value as here with `range(5)`)

Comment: @mgc This version of drop doesn't do what OP is expecting. For example, `reindex` is already making a copy of the data.